# Error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable 'crypto' must be of type 'Crypto', but here has type 'Crypto'

Tags: angular, typescript

From today we are having issues with deploying our project as in drone logs in build step we are receiving:

Error: node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/crypto.d.ts:4477:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'crypto' must be of type 'Crypto', but here has type 'Crypto'.

4477 var crypto: webcrypto.Crypto;
~~~~~~
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:18084:13

```
18084 declare var crypto: Crypto;
                  ~~~~~~
'crypto' was also declared here.
```

Here are the project dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^14.1.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^13.0.0",
    "@nrwl/angular": "15.7.2",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
    "angular-ng-stepper": "^2.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.9.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "ngx-json-viewer": "^3.2.1",
    "ngx-progressbar": "^9.0.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^14.0.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^15.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.1.3",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.1.0",
    "@nrwl/nx-cloud": "15.0.0",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "15.7.2",
    "@schematics/angular": "^14.2.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.5",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.2.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "nx": "15.7.2",
    "prettier": "^2.8.4",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  }
```

We saw that this issue has been reported on github: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/68379 but installing the @types/node@20.11.5 does not solve the issue...

Drone config for build:

```
      commands:
        - npm install
        - npm run build-stage
```

How can we fix this issue as the issue is not happening when building the project locally..?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wagner's answer should work. Just keep in mind that using a carat symbol (^) in your version "^20.11.5" means you are willing to accept any version of the dependency from 20.11.5 up to but not including 21.0.0. Try removing the carat from your dependency version to see if that works.

[See the response here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)

Comment: I dont know if there is a way to accept both of your answers as a solution. The issue was with the carat symbol (^). Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary workaround for me, was to use resolutions on package.json to force downgrading to version 20.11.7:

"@types/node" : "20.11.7"

Will be fixed [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/68371)

Comment: But as you can see we've included an even lower version "@types/node": "^20.11.5", and the issue still persists upon building the app.